# All but one formatter must use --out, only one can print to each stream (or STDOUT) (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, calabash

Getting the above error when trying to run a feature file. I updated the calabash cucumber to 0.18.2. Since then i am getting this issue. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have more than one formatter defined.  Check your config/cucumber.yml or ./cucumber.yml file.  Look for defined formatters like --json or --html.  You should also check the version of cucumber you are using.  Recently, Calabash iOS and Android dropped the cucumber < 2.0 requirement.  You might be experiencing a change between cucumber 1.x and cucumber 2.x.  If you want to force cucumber 1.x, use a Gemfile and bundle exec to enforce the change.